# Filter a CollectionViewSource and then sort manually

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I have an `ObservableCollection<Recipe>` which is bound to an `ICollectionView`. It is possible to filter by my personal predicate implementation. The `ICollectionView` is bound on a `dataGrid`.

Now I would like to reorder the list of `Recipes` after the the collection has been filtered.

*A recipe got a property 'Identifier'. If you have typed in exactly the identifier of the recipe, it should be placed on top of the list.*

An example:

- 12345
- 1234
- 123

If you type `1234` into the filter, the `Recipe` with `Identifier = 1234` should be placed an top of the list instead of beeing on second place.

```
public ICollectionView RecipeCollection
{
    get => _RecipeCollection;
    set
    {
        _RecipeCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private ICollectionView _RecipeCollection;


Recipes = new ObservableCollection<Recipe>(databaseQuery.Result);
RecipeCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Recipes);
RecipeCollection.Filter = CollectionViewSource_Filter;



private bool CollectionViewSource_Filter(object item)
{
    if (item is Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchBox.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }

        string filter = SearchBox.Text.ToLower();
        if (recipe.Identifier.ToLower().Contains(filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipe.Name) && recipe.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipe.Description) && recipe.Description.ToLower().Contains(filter))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `SortOrder` property to the `Recipe` class and a new `SortDescription(nameof(Recipe.SortOrder), ListSortDirection.Ascending)` to the `SortDescriptions` property of the `ICollectionView`. You then set the value of the `SortOrder` property of all `Recipe` objects according to the sort order you want. This should reorder the list of recipes.

Depending on your requirements, you may want to use a `CollectionViewSource` with live sorting enabled: https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/16/988-enabling-live-sorting-in-a-collectionviewsource/

As pointed out by @redcurry, if you use a `ListCollectionView`, there is a `CustomSort` property that you can set to an `IComparer`.

Comment: I had already thought about adding a separate property. Is it possible to do this without it?

Comment: Only if you can sort by any of the other properties. Unfortunately there is no "Sort" predicate property.

Comment: Actually, if your collection view (`ICollectionView`) is a `ListCollectionView`, and it most likely is, you can assign it a `CustomSort`. This is an `IComparer`, where you can customize how to sort your objects. In your case, you'll need to additionally pass in the search text (in its constructor), so that you can properly sort based on whether it matches exactly.

Comment: @redcurry: Good catch. I modified my answer to include this option as well.

Comment: @redcurry This was exactly my second approach to solve this problem. But by adding a second property it seems to be the more elegant way 